# Fancybox popup iframe content is not displaying in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, fancybox

I am using **fancybox 1.3.X**, I have iframe, inside i have got a button, clicking on that fancybox popup iframe will be loaded, the content of the iframe is **getting loaded from a file**, Its working nicely in all the browsers except **IE**. In IE **content wont display** but **only the popup** will appear.Is there any work around for this.

The piece of code is shown below.

```
$("a.iframe").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'           :   600, 
            'speedOut'          :   200, 
            'overlayShow'       :   false,
            'width'             :   250,
            'height'            :   190,
            'type'              :   'iframe'

            });
```

and I am calling form here

```
<iframe name="report" id="report">
    <a class="iframe" href="edit-details.php?id=8">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding autoSize: VALUE sorted out my IE loading issue. Give it a shot.
Skweekah

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` on the last line? Or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be browser compatibility problem ,,

try this :-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

or first check your code IE is very much case sensetive. check if give any html error or tags..

run this code in validator,

check your script again ///

Comment: Yes, I haven't mentioned the html tags: <html><body>. now the content is loading but the popup iframe is not displaying properly

Comment: that's y .. please give a proper format of coding.. did u try browser compatiblity .. is it working..

Comment: Was there a resolution to this problem? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Its really not nice code, but i solved this problem by reloading the frame within the afterShow and onUpdate eventhandler. For me, after this workaround, IE displays the content now.

```
var bUpdateOnce = true;

$(".fb2").fancybox({
  autoResize : true,
  autoCenter : true,
  autoSize : true,

  onUpdate : updateIFrame,
  afterShow : updateIFrame,
  beforeShow : function() {
    bUpdateOnce = true;
  },
  ...
  ..

function updateIFrame() {
    // ie fix, if not, window is empty
    if(bUpdateOnce) {
        bUpdateOnce = false;
        //reload all iFrames
        $('iframe').each(function() {
            this.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this
try to add this
try to add this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```